# Pandas mean() for multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have df:

```
CU           Parameters           1       2       3
379-H   Output Energy, (Wh/h)   0.045   0.055   0.042
349-J   Output Energy, (Wh/h)   0.001   0.003   0
625-H   Output Energy, (Wh/h)   2.695   1.224   1.272
626-F   Output Energy, (Wh/h)   1.381   1.494   1.3
```

I would like to create two separate dfs, getting the mean of column values by grouping index on level 0 (CU):

df1: (379-H and 625-H)

```
Parameters                1     2      3
Output Energy, (Wh/h)    1.37   0.63   0.657
```

df2: (the rest)

```
Parameters                 1     2      3
Output Energy, (Wh/h)     0.69  0.74   0.65
```

I can get the mean for all using by grouping level 1:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna(how='all').groupby(level=1).mean()
```

but how do I group these according to level 0?

SOLUTION:

```
lightsonly = ["379-H", "625-H"]
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').dropna(how='all')
mask = df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(lightsonly)
df1 = df[mask].groupby(level=1).mean()
df2 = df[~mask].groupby(level=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) + [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) for `True` and `False` index and then get [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) with `rename` by `dict`:

```
d = {True: '379-H and 625-H', False: 'the rest'}
df.index = df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(['379-H', '625-H'])
df = df.mean(level=0).rename(d)
print (df)
                     1       2      3
the rest         0.691  0.7485  0.650
379-H and 625-H  1.370  0.6395  0.657
```

For separately `dfs` is possible also use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask= df.index.get_level_values(0).isin(['379-H', '625-H'])

df1 = df[mask].mean().rename('379-H and 625-H').to_frame().T
print (df1)
                    1       2      3
379-H and 625-H  1.37  0.6395  0.657

df2 = df[~mask].mean().rename('the rest').to_frame().T
print (df2)
              1       2     3
the rest  0.691  0.7485  0.65
```

Another `numpy` solution with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
a1 = df[mask].values.mean(axis=0)
#alternatively
#a1 = df.values[mask].mean(axis=0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a1.reshape(-1, len(a1)), index=['379-H and 625-H'], columns=df.columns)
print (df1)
                    1       2      3
379-H and 625-H  1.37  0.6395  0.657
```

Comment: Glad can help, I think `df1 = df[mask].groupby(level=1).mean()` is same as `df1 = df[mask].mean(level=1)`. Nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the dataframe `df` where `CU` and `Parameters` are assumed to be in the index.

```
                                 1      2      3
CU    Parameters                                
379-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)  0.045  0.055  0.042
349-J Output Energy, (Wh/h)  0.001  0.003  0.000
625-H Output Energy, (Wh/h)  2.695  1.224  1.272
626-F Output Energy, (Wh/h)  1.381  1.494  1.300
```

Then we can groupby the truth values of whether the first level values are in the list `['379-H', '625-H']`.

```
m = {True: 'Main', False: 'Rest'}
l = ['379-H', '625-H']
g = df.index.get_level_values('CU').isin(l)
df.groupby(g).mean().rename(index=m)

          1       2      3
Rest  0.691  0.7485  0.650
Main  1.370  0.6395  0.657
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Use a lambda function to change index to 2 groups and then groupby using the modified index.
df.groupby(by=lambda x:'379-H,625-H' if x[0] in ['379-H','625-H'] else 'Others').mean()
Out[22]: 
                 1       2      3
379-H,625-H  1.370  0.6395  0.657
Others       0.691  0.7485  0.650
```